# Send data using different IP while using incognito?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, ip, ipv4, incognito-mode

When I access a particular site through Google Chrome, that site's server will have my IP. Is there a way I can access that site through Incognito Window such that it shows a different IP?

Essentially, I want to login to the site from a normal window as well as an incognito window at the same time, but the site's servers should show different IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how incognito works.  The IP is based on our machine, router etc that Chrome can't change as it is all based on the network stack.

You could look at using a VPN extension that runs in incognito mode.